# EC2 Security Group not connecting to my IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Seems like a basic job, but for some reason it is not working for me. I wish to access my EC2 instances from my office IP only.

I went into my security group and added an SSH rule with source for my IP only like this -

[image]

But this does not seems to be working for me at all. I get connection denied when I try to connect via WinSCP or by using terminal.

Everything works if I change my source to Everywhere (0.0.0.0/0)
Anyone has any pointer for me please.

Comment: I'm sure you've covered that, but make sure that whatever IP address the Security Group console uses for the "My IP" option is correct.  If you're able to SSH with the source set to 0.0.0.0/0 and not when it's set to your IP address, than odds are the IP address is incorrect.  Try going to www.whatismyip.com?

Comment: Yeah I have tested that a few times now.

Comment: Have you check the ip in the security log that is associated to the ssh login when access from everywhere is enable?  It may be that http traffic is routed via some proxy.

Comment: Sorry, then I am out of ideas as that's a very basic function.  Try emailing AWS Support?  Even under the free tier, they should support something like that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Login to the EC2 using the method that works and issue the command

`who am i`

It will say something like

```
ec2-user      pts/0        2016-02-29 15:06 (104.66.242.192)
```

Use the ip address shown for you (not the one above) in the security group rule

Comment: Quite often they are altered by routing and NAT along the way.  Best thing to do is to find what AWS sees in the end

Comment: Another route that doesn't require opening up to 0.0.0.0/0 is to setup Flow Logs in the VPC, attempt a failed connection and then check the Flow Logs to see what IP is being rejected. My company flags Security Groups with 0.0.0.0/0 as the source IP, so if anyone has similar security restrictions then Flow Logs are the way to go.

Comment: who am i command is perfect solution.
In my case , the security group was properly configured but I forgot to associate the proper route table to the subnet that was thereason I was not getting the response from theEc2 insatnce back to my host.

Answer (score 2):

Although "who am i" work fine. However I'd like to add two more solutions.
both are very easy.

**Solution 1:**

Step 1: Open security group for all IP's (0.0.0.0/0) for a while.

Step 2: Make ssh connection to your server.

Step 3: run "w" command and check the output in FROM column.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-228:~$ w
 23:20:09 up 5 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.08, 0.08, 0.04
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
ubuntu   pts/0    52.95.75.17      23:20    0.00s  0.01s  0.00s w
```

Step 4: Replace this IP in the security group with 0.0.0.0/0 ( like 52.95.75.17/32 ).

**Solution 2:**

Step 1: Open security group for all IP's (0.0.0.0/0) for a while.

Step 2: Make ssh connection to your server.

Step 3: Check the last login info on welcome message.
like :

```
Learn more about enabling ESM Apps service at https://ubuntu.com/esm


Last login: Thu Feb  9 23:21:42 2023 from 52.95.75.17
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-228:~$
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-228:~$
```

Step 4 ( optional ): If IP address not available in welcome message. Then run "last" command.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-228:~$
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-228:~$ last
ubuntu   pts/2        52.95.75.17      Thu Feb  9 23:33   still logged in
ubuntu   pts/1        52.95.75.17      Thu Feb  9 23:21   still logged in
```

Step 5: Replace this IP in the security group with 0.0.0.0/0 ( like 52.95.75.17/32 ).

Check below screenshot for reference of above solutions:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Feel free to use my powershell script for this .

The script detects your public ip and adds it to the inbound security group rules of dedicated RDP and SSH security groups .

If these groups do not exist , the script will create them and add it to the appropriate instances .

https://github.com/manuelh2410/public/blob/1/AWSIP_Linux_Win.ps1

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)